# How to change the $PATH in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, bash, git, path

I've installed git via the instaler and not with terminal with commands, and my $PATH changed, the path to the 'local' git was added the the end of the variable, and my $PATH changed to this:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

However, that doesnt help me, because i the path to Xcode's git comes first.

so what I've done is the next, I added this lines to my '.bash_profile':

```
export PATH="/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH"
```

and now my path is the next:

```
/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

And I wanted to know how to remove the duplication from the end of the Path so I end up with:

```
/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Thanks Ahead! And sorry if my english is too bad..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The git installer created `/etc/paths.d/git`. You can remove the path entry by running `sudo rm /etc/paths.d/git`.

Comment: I dont want to remove the folder from the hard drive, but only from the pahth variable

Comment: The files in paths.d are used to configure the path. /etc/paths.d/git just contains one line that adds /usr/local/git/bin to the path.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply edit the actual `.bash_profile` file. However, it is hidden, so accessing it can be a bit of a pain. Here are a couple of ways:

**NOTE: FOR ALL METHODS, SAVE THE FILE AS A PLAIN TXT!**

### With Terminal

If you are comfortable with using `Terminal`, you can type

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

And edit the file from there. To save and exit, press `Control + X` to exit. Then, press 'Y' to save your changes, and simply hit `Enter` to use that path.

### A bit of Terminal, but with an GUI editor

If you would rather use an actual editor, I would suggest using Text Edit so that the file remains a plain .txt, no formatting. To do this, you need to make hidden files visible. (Hidden files are the ones with a `.` before it)

Unfortunately, the easiest way still involves Terminal. To make files visible or hidden(respectively), type the following

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
or
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles NO
```

And then you need to [relaunch Finder.](http://www.wikihow.com/Relaunch-Finder-on-a-Mac)

Then you can open the file which is in the [main user directory](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2549) (Yes, that page is outdated, but it does tell you what you need to know).

### No Terminal at all

If you want to avoid Terminal all together, you can download apps such as [invisibliX](http://www.read-write.fr/invisiblix/) to automatically toggle the visibility of hidden files. With that particular app, simply press the magnifying glass to toggle visibility.

Again, I suggest Text Editor for editing the file, which is located in the [main user directory](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2549) (Yes, that page is outdated, but it does tell you what you need to know)